# canvas setLineDash with array doesn't work in Firefox but in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, html5-canvas

i have following code:

```
[
    {
      lineDash: [0, 0],
      strokeStyle: '#909090',
      lineWidth: lineWidth,
    },
    {
      lineDash: [0, 0],
      strokeStyle: '#e5e5e5',
      lineWidth: lineWidth -10,
    },
    {
      lineDash: [0, 0],
      strokeStyle: '#909090',
      lineWidth: lineWidth -26,
    },
    {
      lineDash: [20, 14],
      strokeStyle: '#ffffff',
      lineWidth: 3,
    },
  ].forEach(function(entry) {

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.lineWidth = entry.lineWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = entry.strokeStyle;
    ctx.setLineDash(entry.lineDash);
}
```

Setting lineWidth and strokeStyle works fine, but setLineWidth doesn't in Firefox and i get no error in console. In Chrome, it works. If i say instead of 'ctx.setLineDash(entry.lineDash);' 'ctx.setLineDash(entry.lineDash[0], entry.lineDash[1]);', Firefox console says 'TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.setLineDash can't be converted to a sequence.' and Chrome console means 'Uncaught TypeError: The 1st argument is neither an array, nor does it have indexed properties'.

Do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know, i know the fault: [0, 0] doesn't make a line (0 line, 0 space between!?). I have to set the first value to any number over 0 and let the other 0. Then, it's a solid line.